# How to merge lists from a loop in jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to determine the rows in a data frame that has the same value in some special columns (sex, work class, education).

```
new_row_data=df.head(20)
new_center_clusters =new_row_data.head(20)
for j in range(len(new_center_clusters)):
  row=[]
  for i in range(len(new_row_data)):         
    if (new_center_clusters.iloc[j][5] == new_row_data.iloc[i][5]):
        if(new_center_clusters.iloc[j][2] == new_row_data.iloc[i][2]):
            if(new_center_clusters.iloc[j][3] == new_row_data.iloc[i][3]):
                if(new_center_clusters.iloc[j][0] != new_center_clusters.iloc[i][0]):
                    row.append(new_center_clusters.iloc[j][0])
                    row.append(new_center_clusters.iloc[i][0])
                    myset = list(set(row))
                    myset.sort()         
print(myset)
```

[image: DataFrame]

I need a list that includes all the IDs of similar rows in one list. but I can not merge all the lists in one list.

I get this result:

[image: My result]

I need to get like this:
[1,12,8,17,3,18,4,19,5,13,6,9]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Looks like you need `pd.groupby` with columns `workclass` & `education` ?

Comment: I need one list that includes these IDs together not separated.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), also there are 2 DataFrames `new_center_clusters` and `new_row_data`, so one missing

Comment: I wanted to know which rows are similar in terms of (sex, education, and workclass). I got the right answer something like this (I didn't bring the duplicated lists):
[1, 12]
[3, 18]
[4, 19]
[5, 13]
[6, 9]
[8, 17]
 
But I need all of them in one list:[1,12,3,18,4,19,5,13,8,17]. Since I need to remove these rows(according to their IDs) to continue my next cluster.

Answer (score 0):

if you want combine all list

```
a=[1,3,4]
b=[2,4,1]
a.extend(b)
```

it will give output as:

```
[1,3,4,2,4,1]
```

similary if you want to remove the duplicates, convert it into set and again list:

```
c=list(set(a))
```

it will give output as:

```
[1,3,4,2]
```